# ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar, trying to create football passmap using matplotlib (mplsoccer)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
pitch = mplsoccer.Pitch(pitch_color='#101010', line_color='white')
fig, ax = pitch.draw(figsize=(16, 8))

arrows = pitch.arrows(pass_map_df_team1["startX"], pass_map_df_team1["startY"],
                      pass_map_df_team1["endX"], pass_map_df_team1["endY"],
                      ax=ax,
                      width=1,
                      color="green")
ax.set_title(pass_map_df_team1["possession_team.name"].unique().item(), fontsize=30)
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_12976/1756201251.py in <module>
      7                       width=1,
      8                       color="green")
----> 9 np.int(ax.set_title(pass_map_df_team1["possession_team.name"].unique().item(), fontsize=30))

ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

i tried to create football passmap
showing this error makes me stuck

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: share `pass_map_df_team1` and I can fix this